# What happens to mutex acquirement in wait()/signal() block?

Tags: multithreading, operating-system, synchronization, mutex, semaphore

So the description of the exercise:
You have this restaurant in which there are N points where you can ask for a portion of fries. Each point has M portions. There is 1 frycheff. When an order-point has 2 portions, it warns the cheff that it needs a refill. The cheff delivers the portions in order of FIFO.
We made this pseudo-code:

```
      init {
    Semafoor[] mutex;
    Condition[] cond_point = new Condition[N];
    int[] portions = new int[N];
    ArrayList<int> waitline = new ArrayList<int>();

    for(int i = 0; i < N; i++) {
        mutex[i] = new Semafoor(1);
        portions[i] = M;
    }
}

point(int n) {
    while(1) {
        mutex[n].acquire();
        if(portions[n] == 0) {
            cond_point[n].wait(mutex[n]);
        }
        else if(portios[n] == 2) {
            waitline.add(n);
        }
        portions[n]--;
        mutex[n].release();
    }
}

frycheff() {
    int n;
    while(1) {
        if(!waitline.empty()) {
            n = waitline.remove(0);
            mutex[n].acquire();
            portions[n] += M;
            cond_point[n].signal();
            mutex[n].release();
        }
    }
}
```

So we were wondering what happens when the `wait()` statement blocks the `point(int n)` signal. In our documentary it says they release the mutex in an atomic way, so there is no interference. But what about the other lines of code? (in the `point(int n)` function)? Are the `portions[n]`-- etc. - lines discarded? Will the `signal()` statement recall to the `point(int n)` function but in a reset manner so the function will run as new?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Why do you think the `portions[n]--;` is discarded? I have the feeling that you think wait/signal are something like jump instructions but that's not the case.

Comment: because the mutex is released

Comment: ah, I see - the mutex is reaquired before wait() returns.

Answer (score 1):

The man page of `wait()` has further information about the behaviour. It talks about the pthread implementation specifically but this applies to every implementation in general.
https://linux.die.net/man/3/pthread_cond_wait

The most important parts are these:

---

> pthread_cond_wait() functions shall block on a condition variable

`wait()` is a blocking call. The thread is put to sleep by the scheduler. `wait()` will return when a signal is received. There are no jumps. The execution will continue right after `wait()`.

**Note:** Because of *spurious wakeups* it is possible that `wait()` returns without good reason. You should therefore check if the condition really is met. Call `wait()` in a loop:

```
// Condition: portions[n] > 0
while(portions[n] == 0)
    cond_point[n].wait(mutex[n]);
```

---

> They shall be called with mutex locked by the calling thread or undefined behavior results.

The mutex already needs to be locked when `wait()` is called.

---

> Upon successful return, the mutex shall have been locked and shall be owned by the calling thread.

When `wait()` returns it will have reacquired the lock. Anything else makes no sense and would lead to confusing situations, as you have seen.

---

So this is what will (could) happen:

```
--- point ------------------------- frycheff -------------------
mutex[n].acquire();                 Serving other Points
else if(portios[n] == 2)            Serving other Points
waitline.add(n);                    Serving other Points
portions[n]--;                      Serving other Points
mutex[n].release();                 Serving other Points
...
mutex[n].acquire(); (BLOCKS)        if(!waitline.empty())
mutex[n].acquire();                 n = waitline.remove(0);
if(portions[n] == 0)                mutex[n].acquire(); (BLOCKS)
cond_point[n].wait(mutex[n]);       mutex[n].acquire();
Sleeping                            portions[n] += M;
Sleeping                            cond_point[n].signal();
wait() reaquires mutex[n]           mutex[n].release();
portions[n]--;                      if(!waitline.empty())
mutex[n].release();                 if(!waitline.empty())
```

Btw: You should probably use another mutex to synchronize the frycheff's calls to `if(!waitline.empty())` and `n = waitline.remove(0);` because write operations on an ArrayList are not threadsave.