# C++, pthreads: how to stop a worker thread from multiple threads

Tags: c++, multithreading, pthreads

I need to be able to stop a single worker thread from continuing to execute from arbitrary points in arbitrary other threads, including, but not limited to, the main thread. I had produced what I thought was working code last year, but investigations to-day following some thread deadlocks showed that it does not seem to work properly, especially as regards mutexes.

The code needs to run a particular method, path_explorer_t::step(), in a worker thread exactly once for every time that a helper method, start_path_explorer() is called in the main thread. start_path_explorer() is only ever called from the main thread.

Another method, stop_path_explorer() must be able to be called at any time by any thread (other than the thread that runs path_explorer_t::step()), and must not return until it is certain that path_explorer_t::step() has fully completed.

Additionally, path_explorer_t::step() must not be called if karte_t::world->is_terminating_threads() is true, but must instead terminate the thread at the next opportunity. The thread must not terminate in other circumstances.

The code that I have written to do this is as follows:

```
    void* path_explorer_threaded(void* args)
    {
        karte_t* world = (karte_t*)args;
        path_explorer_t::allow_path_explorer_on_this_thread = true;
        karte_t::path_explorer_step_progress = 2;

        do
        {
            simthread_barrier_wait(&start_path_explorer_barrier);
            karte_t::path_explorer_step_progress = 0;
            simthread_barrier_wait(&start_path_explorer_barrier);
            pthread_mutex_lock(&path_explorer_mutex);

            if (karte_t::world->is_terminating_threads())
            {
                karte_t::path_explorer_step_progress = 2;
                pthread_mutex_unlock(&path_explorer_mutex);
                break;
            }

            path_explorer_t::step();

            karte_t::path_explorer_step_progress = 1;

            pthread_cond_signal(&path_explorer_conditional_end);
            karte_t::path_explorer_step_progress = 2;
            pthread_mutex_unlock(&path_explorer_mutex);
        } while (!karte_t::world->is_terminating_threads());

        karte_t::path_explorer_step_progress = -1;
        pthread_exit(NULL);
        return args;
    }


    void karte_t::stop_path_explorer()
    {
    #ifdef MULTI_THREAD_PATH_EXPLORER
        pthread_mutex_lock(&path_explorer_mutex);

        if (path_explorer_step_progress = 0)
        {
            pthread_cond_wait(&path_explorer_conditional_end, &path_explorer_mutex);
        }

        pthread_mutex_unlock(&path_explorer_mutex);
    #endif
    }

    void karte_t::start_path_explorer()
    {
    #ifdef MULTI_THREAD_PATH_EXPLORER
        if (path_explorer_step_progress == -1)
        {
            // The threaded path explorer has been terminated, so do not wait
            // or else we will get a thread deadlock.
            return;
        }
        pthread_mutex_lock(&path_explorer_mutex);
        if (path_explorer_step_progress > 0)
        {
            simthread_barrier_wait(&start_path_explorer_barrier);
        }
        if(path_explorer_step_progress > -1)
        {
            simthread_barrier_wait(&start_path_explorer_barrier);
        }
        pthread_mutex_unlock(&path_explorer_mutex);
    #endif 
    }
```

However, I find that, for reasons that I do not understand, the mutex lock in stop_path_explorer() does not work properly, and it does not prevent the mutex lock line from being passed in path_explorer_threaded, with the consequence that it is possible for the thread calling stop_path_explorer() to be waiting at the cond_wait and the worker thread itself to be waiting at the top barrier underneath "do". It also seems to be able to produce conditions in which the mutex can be unlocked twice, which gives rise to undefined behaviour unless I set it to recursive.

Do I just need to set the mutex attribute to recursive and add an extra unlock inside the conditional statement in stop_path_explorer(), or is a more fundamental redesign needed? If the latter, has anyone any suggestions as to how to go about it?

Thank you in advance for any help.

Comment: `if (path_explorer_step_progress = 0)` should be `while (path_explorer_step_progress == 0)`. (Notice there are two changes.) Also, waiting on a barrier while holding a mutex is suspicious.

Comment: Additionally, you may want to see [CppCon 2014: Lisa Lippincott "How to call C libraries from C++"](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3ZO0V4Prefc).

Comment: Thank you very much for your reply. I have tried making the amendment that you suggested. (As an aside, for some reason, I uploaded the wrong version of the code fragment, I think a version to which I had changed it recently for testing. The original line was actually 

"if (path_explorer_step_progress < 2 && path_explorer_step_progress >= 0)"

I do not think that the alteration to a while loop helps, however: I still get the mutex passed in path_explorer_threaded when the mutex has been locked in stop_path_explorer.

I suspect that I have made a fundamental error here.

Comment: I think that the mutex is double locked in some cases, as pthread_cond_wait will lock the mutex over and above the explicit lock command. This results in undefined behaviour, I think, but I am somewhat unclear on what alternative code could sensibly work here to do the same job.

Comment: You have to call `pthread_cond_wait` in a loop because of _spurious wakeups_.

Comment: 1000ml - thank you for that. How calling pthread_cond_wait in a loop actually work, though, so as to deal with a spurious wakeup? I cannot immediately see how having it in a loop would, in and of itself, make any difference.

Comment: Well calling it without a loop is undefined behavior. You have to repeatedly check the condition which you are waiting for until it is met. Please update the code in the question with the current one. And while you're at it, remove the macros too, because that's just noise.

Comment: Thank you for your reply: that is helpful. As you will see from my self-answer below, I have rewritten the code and added a loop as suggested, which seems to work. I will leave the macros in for the time being, as I need to be able to disable the multi-threading for testing purposes on occasion.

As set out in my self-answer below, the new code may still not be correct, so I should appreciate any feedback on that. 

Thank you again.

Answer (score 0):

Having investigated this further, I think that I have a potential answer to my own question.

I had misunderstood how pthread_cond_wait() works in conjunction with the mutex - the documentation says that it *locks*, not unlocks the mutex passed to it.

This means that the mutex was getting double locked from the same thread, which created undefined behaviour, and may well have resulted in some of the odd problems that I was seeing.

I have now rewritten the code as follows with a second mutex (new definitions not shown in the code sample):

```
    void* path_explorer_threaded(void* args)
    {
        karte_t* world = (karte_t*)args;
        path_explorer_t::allow_path_explorer_on_this_thread = true;
        karte_t::path_explorer_step_progress = 2;
        int mutex_error = 0;

        do
        {
            simthread_barrier_wait(&start_path_explorer_barrier);
            karte_t::path_explorer_step_progress = 0;
            simthread_barrier_wait(&start_path_explorer_barrier);   

            if (karte_t::world->is_terminating_threads())
            {
                karte_t::path_explorer_step_progress = 2;
                break;
            }

            path_explorer_t::step();

            mutex_error = pthread_mutex_lock(&path_explorer_mutex);
            karte_t::path_explorer_step_progress = 1;
            mutex_error = pthread_mutex_unlock(&path_explorer_mutex);

            pthread_cond_signal(&path_explorer_conditional_end);

            mutex_error = pthread_mutex_lock(&path_explorer_mutex);
            karte_t::path_explorer_step_progress = 2;
            mutex_error = pthread_mutex_unlock(&path_explorer_mutex);

        } while (!karte_t::world->is_terminating_threads());

        karte_t::path_explorer_step_progress = -1;
        pthread_exit(NULL);
        return args;
    }


    void karte_t::stop_path_explorer()
    {
    #ifdef MULTI_THREAD_PATH_EXPLORER
        int mutex_error = 0;

        while (path_explorer_step_progress == 0)
        {
            mutex_error = pthread_mutex_lock(&path_explorer_mutex);
            pthread_cond_wait(&path_explorer_conditional_end, &path_explorer_cond_mutex);
            if (&path_explorer_mutex)
            {
                mutex_error = pthread_mutex_unlock(&path_explorer_mutex);
                mutex_error = pthread_mutex_unlock(&path_explorer_cond_mutex);
            }
        }

    #endif
    }

    void karte_t::start_path_explorer()
    {
    #ifdef MULTI_THREAD_PATH_EXPLORER
        if (path_explorer_step_progress == -1)
        {
            // The threaded path explorer has been terminated, so do not wait
            // or else we will get a thread deadlock.
            return;
        }
        if (path_explorer_step_progress > 0)
        {
            simthread_barrier_wait(&start_path_explorer_barrier);
        }
        if(path_explorer_step_progress > -1)
        {
            simthread_barrier_wait(&start_path_explorer_barrier);
        }
    #endif 
    }
```

However, I do not believe that this code is working fully correctly. The software from which this is taken, an open source computer game, is designed to be playable over the internet in a multi-player configuration using lockstep networking (meaning that the server and client must execute the code from the defined start point exactly deterministically or they will get out of sync). When using this code, the clients will eventually go out of sync with the server, whereas they would not with the original code (provided, that is, that server and client were running identical executables: I was having trouble with client and server going out of sync when the executables were differently compiled, e.g. GCC and Visual Studio, and I suspect that the undefined behaviour might be the culprit there).

If anyone can confirm whether my new code is correct or has any noticeable flaws, I should be very grateful.

Comment: How you handled the mutex for `pthread_cond_wait` seemed okay before. You have to call it with a locked mutex. The mutex is released while the thread is sleeping and reaquired afterwards.
See https://stackoverflow.com/a/41333292/1442598